# FaunaDB shows "Instance data is not valid." when trying to update schema

Tags: graphql, faunadb

I am trying to upload an updated `schema.gql` file to Fauna/FaunaDB via the GraphQL console's 'Update schema' button.

I am receiving the following error:

```
Instance data is not valid.
```

Does anyone know what the cause of this error message is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen for a variety of reasons--for example, you might have a document that's incompatible with your new schema. Most of the time, it is related to the import process trying to modify an existing index.

One option is to completely override your schema. Be careful when you do this though, and be sure to read exactly what "override" entails on this page (CTRL + F for "override"):
https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/endpoints

You might need to save your database first before re-uploading your schema.